# Label "for" and Input "id"

Tags: html, input, accessibility

I'm currently working on a forms module for a CMS so that our users can create their own forms to display on their website and I'm trying to make sure it's all accessible with labels etc.

My question is, if you have a `<label>` for an `<input>` with a `[for]` attribute to link to the `[id]` of the input, does the `[id]` have to actually *mean* something? Is it read? Or is it just to link them?

Eg.

```
<label for="input1">Name</label>
<input id="input1" />
```

or

```
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input id="name" />
```

Will these have the same or different results on a screen reader?

Comment: it doesn't have to mean anything but it's good practice to label it something logical so that others including your future self won't get confused

Comment: Completely aside from anything else, for your own *sanity* try to make the names meaningful.

Comment: When doing my own html, my ids are meaningful, but in this situation as I'm looping though a database, the ids would be input1, input2 input3 etc.

Comment: The following is also valid markup if you can't use the `for`: `<label>Name<input id="name" /></label>`

Comment: I have read that somewhere else but the `label` is in a separate div to the `input`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> If you have a `<label>` for an `<input>` with a `[for]` attribute to link to the `[id]` of the input, does the `[id]` have to actually mean something?

Browser semantics* refer to how a browser will identify a DOM node and what the browser will read to users who use assistive navigation.

The `[id]` and `[class]` attributes **do not** add to semantics. It's important to still use descriptive IDs and classes where possible, but only insofar as to make development easier.

> Is it read?

No. As far as I'm aware, the `[id]` attribute is never read directly to a user through normal operation of a website. See my note below about the document fragment identifier.

> Or is it just to link them?

It tells the label which `<input>` (or `<select>` or `<textarea>`…) the label is labeling, and also provides some UI features such as moving focus to the relevant input when the label is clicked, tapped, or otherwise triggered.

When a labelled element is focused, browsers will know to tell the screen reader to read the label associated with the element.

---

What about the `[name]` attribute?

In a `<form>` screen readers won't read a `[name]` attribute because it doesn't indicate anything semantic, however for `GET` requests the `[name]` attribute will be used as a key in the query string. Query strings *may* be read to users, so it's worth considering using a human-readable `[name]` rather than something auto-generated.

---

What about document fragment identifiers?

If you're planning on using an `[id]` to `<a>`nchor down the page, then the value of the `[id]` attribute may be read when it becomes the hash of the URL. Just like with the `[name]` attribute it may be worth considering using a human-readable `[id]` for these cases.

---

<sub>*a word whose definition is meaning, which makes discussing its own meaning…difficult and quite meta</sub>

Comment: @Liam, I believe I just added a note about that near the end. This answer is still very much a work in progress. Let me know if you notice anything else I should add.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That makes sense. I normally would use descriptive ids but as it's in a loop, they are named input1, input2, input3 etc.

Answer (score 1):

No, not what so ever.

If you put yourself in a situation where either the `id` or `class` is visible to the user then you have probably done something horribly wrong, or you are trying to have an unnatural level of code transparency (which could, for example, be suitable in a class-room situation).

The `class` and `id` attributes are just there for programming purposes. They should follow the naming conventions you have set for yourself and make as much sense as possible from the programmer's point of view.